# RewriteCond for either .com or .org

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way I can simplify this code so I dont have to check .com and .org separately?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydirectory(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /mydirectory/$1    [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydirectory(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /mydirectory/$1    [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can take regex help for that. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.(com|org)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydirectory(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydirectory/$1 [L]
```

Take note of `(org|com)` which makes that patter match both `.org` and `.com`